# Getting a second login prompt when attempting to open a link to a word doc

Tags: iis, ms-word

I have created a simple website, that lists word documents stored on our server.  Our site is using basic authentication with SSL certificate.  So when the user first goes to the site, they are prompted for a username and password, once they log in and when a user clicks on a  link and clicks "open" to open the word doc (.doc or .docx) he's prompted to login again.  Clicking "Cancel" two times, and the prompt goes away, and the document opens.  How can i remove this second login request?  I've google it and found some issues with users using sharepoint describing the same scenario, but we are not using sharepoint.

Thank you!
-Russ

Comment: If you can reproduce this issue, use Fiddler to analyze the packets can tell why it prompts. If you cannot reproduce it, ask the user to capture the packets and send back to you. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up requesting PDF files instead of word documents.  it seems that IE and Word, using basic authentication will require 2 password requests.  One by IIS when you request the page.  The second comes from Office, when it tries to open the word document.  Could not find a way around this other than to change the requested documents to pdf files, then they opened up fine without the second login.