# httpd 2.4 and AD: Getting prompted twice when opening .docx

Tags: apache, webserver

This is a similar question to this one:
[Getting a second login prompt when attempting to open a link to a word doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525491/getting-a-second-login-prompt-when-attempting-to-open-a-link-to-a-word-doc)
But since that one is 5 years old and went unanswered:

Apache 2.4 running on RHEL 7. Website authenticates via LDAP. Browser is IE 11 on Windows 7(company policy). Everything works fine except opening files that require MS Word to open. When I click on a link to a .docx , if I choose to open the file, I get a second authentication prompt, which goes away after clicking Cancel twice.

If anyone has any idea how to get rid of this prompt, I'd greatly appreciate it.